# Throw an Exception without crashing the app

Tags: java, android, exception, crash-reports

I'm using a crash report library in my Android project. Once activated, it reacts to every uncatched exception and creates a report just before the app shutdown.

So far so good, but I want to add more "control" to this thing and create reports for non-Exceptions too. My idea is to define a "fake" Exception this way:

```
public final class NonFatalError extends RuntimeException {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6259026017799110412L;

    public NonFatalError(String msg) {
        super(msg);
    }
}
```

So, when I want to send a non-fatal error message and create a report, I'll do this:

```
throw new NonFatalError("Warning! A strange thing happened. I report this to the server but I let you continue the job...");
```

If called from the main thread, this obviously makes the app crash. So, I tried to throw it **on a background thread**!

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {     
    @Override
    public void run() {
        throw new NotFatalError("Warning! A strange thing happened. I report this to the server but I let you continue the job...");
    }
}).start();
```

A great idea? No. The app crashes anyway (but the fake crash report is sent as expected). Is there another way to achieve what I want?

Comment: //Is there another way to achieve what I want?// No, you have to catch an exception to stop it crashing the app.

Answer (score 5):

Your exception never gets caught, so that's why your application is crashing.

You can do this do catch the exception from your main thread:

```
Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler h = new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    public void uncaughtException(Thread th, Throwable ex) {
        System.out.println("Uncaught exception: " + ex);
    }
};

Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {     
    @Override
    public void run() {
        throw new NotFatalError("Warning! A strange thing happened. I report this to the server but I let you continue the job...");
    }
});

t.setUncaughtExceptionHandler(h);
t.start();
```

But you can also run the code from your main thread and catch it there.. Like:

```
try
{
  throw new NonFatalError("Warning! blablabla...");
}
catch(NonFatalError e)
{
  System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}
```

Because your exception is extended from the `RuntimeException` class the default behaviour is to exit the application if the exception is not catched anywhere. So that's why you should catch it before the Java Runtime decides to quit the app.

Comment: This method won't kill the app, but it also won't activate the crash report tool.

Comment: @Wessel I'm thinking about making that code one Aspect and code it into annotaion ~

Answer (score 0):

You are using exception to create logs. You shouldnt do that. If you are using a library like crashlytics (https://try.crashlytics.com/) you can send log reports like in this link: http://support.crashlytics.com/knowledgebase/articles/120066-how-do-i-use-logging

The library you are using should have a similar method.

If you want to continue to use Exceptions, you need to catch them to not crash the application.

Comment: I know Crashlytics and I previously worked with it. Now we needed to change some codebase and we switched to the new Parse CrashReport library (http://blog.parse.com/2014/12/09/introducing-parse-crash-reporting-2/)

It's much simpler than Craslytics and does not contain such feature, yet.